# trying to find the question about $\sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac {1}{ak^2+bk+c}$

Tags: support, specific-question

Update : [following search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%20$%5Csum_%7B-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%7B%2b%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%20%7B1%7D%7Bak%5E2%2bbk%2bc%7D$) results : https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=+%24%5Csum_%7B-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%7B%2B%5Cinfty%7D+%5Cfrac+%7B1%7D%7Bak%5E2%2Bbk%2Bc%7D%24 , do not turn into proper format, I am using Chrome and almost every other page looks correct. is the a trick to viewing search results with MathJax applied to them?

Update : Just [found it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161259/what-would-be-the-value-of-sum-limits-n-0-infty-frac1an2bnc) by trying to ask the question again, and viewing the suggestions to view before posting. But is this the normal search method?
Original question below:

I am sure I saw a question regarding summation of $\sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac {1}{ak^2+bk+c}$, but now searching for it I can not find it.

maybe the question was about $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \frac {1}{ak^2+bk+c}$ originally but that does not help in finding the question.

I know I should have bookmarked it as a favourite, but how do the search gurus go about finding it? browsed the tag for [sequences-and-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series) for 300 to 500 without joy, but I am sure the latest activity on that question could have not been more than 3 days ago.

When viewing the questions by "newest" do they get ordered by date of the question or the latest activity data on it ( including edition of question and/or answers/comments ?

Thank you

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/161259/5363)?

Comment: @t.b. yes, but how did you find it? PS: I updated my question before I got your answer.

Comment: Sorry didn't see that update... I just had a look at the things filed under (sequences-series) and it was among the  ten last active questions. There's no trick I can tell you about in this case.

Comment: @t.b. : I started editing the update before your answer but posted  it after you response. Also I ended up with another update. apologies are from me.

Comment: It has always been difficult to search for mathematical entities *without names*, and this case is no different...

Comment: Now that we have Approch0, thing might become simpler. Unfortunately, it seems that it is rather sensitive on difference between [+\infty](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7B%2B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%20%7B1%7D%7Bak%5E2%2Bbk%2Bc%7D%24&p=1) and [\infty](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum%5Climits_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Ban%5E2%2Bbn%2Bc%7D%24&p=1).